# Unexpected Params in Rails 4 controller action

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have a controller in a new rails 4 app which receives a JSON POST call from another application, which is sending minimal params through RestClient:

```
{
 value: 2
 user_email: "person1@example.com"
}
```

However, the params i get in the rails 4 app confuse me

```
{"value" => "2", "user_email" => "person1@example.com", "point" => 
{ "value" => "2", "user_email" } }
```

Why is this happening?

The controller in question (`puts params` produces the hash above)

```
class PointsController < ApplicationController
  # Security, other omitted for brevity
  def create_or_update
    puts params
    @point = Point.where(user_email: params['user_email']).first_or_initialize
    if @point.update_attributes(point_params)
      render json: @point
    else
      render json: @point.errors.messages, status: 422
    end
  end

  private
    def point_params
      params.require(:point).permit(:user_email, :value)
    end
end
```

Comment: Try using this:
`params.respond_to?(:permit) ?
  params.require(:point).permit(:user_email, :value) :
  params[:point].slice(:user_email, :value) rescue nil`